# Do I have to hash the entire key in order to save time-complexity of O(1) on average?

Tags: data-structures, hash, time-complexity, hashtable

Let's say I have hash table and a uniformly distributed hash function and it using separate chaining with linked lists.

The keys saved in the table are pairs `(a,b)` (unlimited numbers), and I insert them to the table according to `hash(a)` (I'm ignoring `b`).

Are the actions `find`, `insert` and `delete` still in `O(1)` time on average? Or do I have to hash the entire key, including `b`?

Comment: @TonyD they could be anything

Answer (score 8, accepted):

No, this will not guarantee you expected O(1) lookups. Imagine, for example, that you hash (0, 0), (0, 1), (0, 2), (0, 3), ..., (0, n-1). All n of these values will hash to the same location in the table (since the second component is ignored), so regardless of how the hash function hashes the first component (0), you will end up with n elements in the same location in a hash table, making your lookups degenerate to taking time Θ(n) in the worst-case.

Generally speaking, you need to hash the entire key when using a hash table. Otherwise, you can easily end up with hash collisions by keeping one part of the key constant and changing the other parts.

Comment: This `O(n) ` worst-case anyway. What about the average case? How does it ruin it?

Comment: @XtremeJoe Whenever you hear "average," you should be thinking "averaged over what?" The traditional analysis of hash tables assumes that the data is chosen non-randomly and that the hash function provides the randomness, and a good hash table implementation should provide good guarantees regardless of what data is provided. To provide an average-case analysis in the way you're proposing, you need to provide a mathematically rigorous description of the probability distribution over possible inputs.

Comment: But in the case I presented, when I know nothing about `b`,  is it possible to achieve `O(1)` average over input

Comment: @XtremeJoe Without knowing anything about the input distribution, you cannot say that the average case would be O(1) because you can't say what you're averaging over.

Comment: @XtremeJoe With only hashing `a` and not `b`, you're essentially increasing the number of collisions by a factor of `b` so the collisions are no longer dependent on a constant, but rather `b` therefore it cannot be constant look up

Comment: @NickZuber: *"increasing...collisions by a factor of `b`* - that's wildly wrong... it doesn't even potentially make sense to talk about `b` as a single *factor*, given it describes a set of variables of unknown distribution, range, and correlation to the associated `a`s.  It's not easy to describe the importance of the `b` distribution and correlation with `a` to the collision rates concisely, but it'd be better to either give a lengthier but meaningful explanation or none at all.

Comment: @TonyD "factor" was a poor choice of words on my part - what I was *trying* to get at was only hashing a would increase the number of average collisions by *some* factor relating to b. If even this proposition is " wildly wrong", I'd love to understand why

Comment: @NickZuber: well, "would" in that sentence is wrong - "may" would be correct.  As a fairly common counter example, if *a* is effectively random with a range far bigger than the hash table size squared, then duplicate values of *a* - and therefore h(a) - will be very uncommon and therefore massively less of a cause of collisions than that inevitable from folding the *h(a)* values into the hash table size; i.e. incorporating *b* when hashing approaches causing about as many new collisions at it resolves.  But, the OP commented nothing's known of a's randomness or range, so best to incorporate b

Answer (score 2):

If you are using `(a, b)` as the key but only storing based on `hash(a)`, then you will have collisions any time you have multiple objects with the same value of `a`.  For example, `(1, 2)` and `(1, 3)` will both hash to the same bucket, so you have to traverse the linked list.  The actual effect on performance depends on your data set, but on average you will **not** still have O(1) performance.

Answer (score 0):

Do you know anything in advance about a and b? If no, you need to hash both. If you know them both to be fairly random then hashing based on a alone should be good enough, although hashing 2 integers shouldn't be more computationally intensive than a single one.

Comment: *"know them both to be fairly random"* is an important insight, though the key thing is whether the range of values `a` can take also significantly exceeds the number of pairs being hashed - if so then collisions are pretty unlikely.  That contrasts with say `a` in the range 0 to 10 while b is 0 to 1 billion: the values could be very random but if you're hashing a million pairs you're getting collisions.